# Open PHP tags inside an @lang()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to pass the value returned from `{[item.document_type]}` inside of a Laravel lang associaction `@lang()` in a blade file but get an undefined variable error in my browser.

`{[item.doucument_type]}` returns a string that is the address needed by `@lang()`.
 However when it is inside the brackets it throws error below, it doesn't work with `$` prefix.

The purpose here is internationalization.

Desired outcome:

```
{[item.filename]} - @lang('app_name.otherlanguagefile'): @lang({[item.document_type]})
```

> Error: Use of undefined constant item - assumed 'item' (this will throw an Error 
>   in a future version of PHP)

The error doesn't throw if `{[item.document_type]}` is outside `@lang()`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `{[` is a valid blade syntax?

Comment: Can you share the exact error message?

Comment: Is `item` a php variable or a javascript variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@lang` expects a string, but you're passing `{[item.document_type]}` which is not a string (it's not quoted) and not a variable, so PHP is trying to interpret it as a constant. That's where the error `Use of undefined constant` is coming from (note that the error says undefined *constant*, not undefined *variable*).

`{[]}` is not a blade tag. Are you using another templating framework (such as javascript) in addition to blade, or are you trying to display the literal brackets to the user, or is this a mistake?

I suspect you want something like `@lang($item['document_type'])` or `@lang($item->document_type)`, assuming `item` is a *PHP* variable being passed to your view.

If `item` is a *javascript* variable, then you cannot access it from your blade template and what you are trying to do is impossible; you will need a completely different approach.

If you want the brackets displayed to the user, then you need something like `{[@lang(...)]}` in your blade view. If it's not a variable, then perhaps you want `{[@lang('item.document_type')]}`

Comment: We are using Javascript as well, i am not trying to display the brackets

Comment: @NaishO'Loughlin is `{[]}` part of your javascript templating?

Comment: this is blade php

Comment: You are right the item is returned in an api call so it cant be passed inside the php as php compiles first. Thanks @travisBritz

Answer (score 1):

use language file parameter with two ways in your laravel blade file.

```
In your file.php inside language folder

<?php

return [
  'variable' => 'this is test message'
];

?>
```

Laravel blade file

```
{{ @lang('file.variable') }} 
            or 
{{ trans('file.variable') }}
```

Your output will be

```
this is test message
```

In your case please use {{ }} blade engine brackets for laravel.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need curly braces if you're passing a parameter to a blade directive, such as `@lang($variable)`.

`{{ $item->filename }} - @lang($app_name->otherlanguagefile): @lang($item->document_type)`??

Comment: `{[item.filename]}` and `{[item.document_type]}` works just not inside lang

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code - how does it solve the problem? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from it

Comment: You dont need curly brackets if it uses $ variable assignment but this doesn't